# What are good places (online) where a community of writers can get together and share their knowledge about writing?

Tags: resources, community

It would be nice to be a member of an online community of people who are knowledgeable about writing, willing to directly help eachother in a format such as Q&A (like here on SE), but also engage in activities out of scope for SE (which could range from general discussion about writing to arranging IRL writing groups), while not depending on a specific technology provider too much (if a community has intrinsic value beyond certain content that it has produced, it should be able to get up and leave from, random example, stack exchange, and move to some other forum; furthermore, it should be able to take its content with it). Are there such places?

This question is obviously motivated by the current misbehaviour of Stack Exchange, the company (as is being discussed on writing.meta.stackexchange.com and meta.stackexchange.com), but it is more general than that, since the Q&A format itself is somewhat limiting.

Comment: Just want to let this be known: SE is (at least seemingly) trying to clean up their act and make amends with the mods and employees they wronged.  I wouldn't abandon Stack Exchange *just* yet.

Comment: Also, I'm not going to vote to close this, but I feel like this belongs on Meta, where we do have a discussion tag.

Comment: @weakdna The question is about resources for writers. It was _motivated_ by SE's terrible behaviour -- which, to me at least, they now seem to be continuing, while _pretending_ to apologise. But the motivation is irrelevant, the question is about what writing communities exist online

Comment: I attempted to establish a writers discord server some months ago, but struggled to find enough interest. Turns out I don't know many writers!

Comment: @sesquipedalias See link in my profile if you are interested in joining. Same goes for anyone else here.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII your discord link is invalid

Comment: @MiloBem Apologies, the link had expired. I have added a fresh one that should remain valid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The Library" which is a Discord server run by writers is a good resource, I have found. There are many published and aspiring authors there and they are quite willing to help with questions, suggestions, critiques etc... and they appear to be very active:

https://writersdiscord.com/

I would also recommend Reddit. There are a number of different writing related subreddits but this would be a key one:

https://www.reddit.com/r/writing/

Answer (score 2):

Try Critique Circle. It's free, although you can pay a subscription to be able to do more cool stuff I guess.

They are an online writing community where you can discuss, research, brainstorm or simply hold friendly debates with fellow writers. Oh, and they will let you critique other's work or vice versa.

https://www.critiquecircle.com/

Comment: Hi nish.feline, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Do you have personal experience using this site? How did it work out for you? Personal experience is always great support for an answer so if you can, [edit] it into your post. Good luck and happy writing!